# Run custom script as part of IFTTT recipe

Tags: if-this-then-that

I've just stared using IFTTT and one of the things I want to do is

```
if 
A NEW TUMBLR POST IS PUBLISHED
run
my-site.com/my-script.php
```

To do this it really needs to be able to ping the URL `my-site.com/my-script.php` is that possible with IFTTT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If This Then That added a channel called "Maker" which supports an action that allows you to send a request to a specific URL with several options. Method (get, post, delete) content type, and content.

It also has a new trigger channel so you can trigger an IFTTT recipe by sending a web request to IFTTT with up to three parameters.

Detailed information can be found here: https://ifttt.com/maker

Comment: This has changed to webhooks for anyone wondering

Comment: @MichaelRusso, how to make the script run every hour / automatically?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to make a request like this to your external site. The site must be one of the services featured on the IFTTT page.

Comment: First statement is flat wrong, second is correct (So I guess I'll give a -1 and +1). Although you must use one of their services, they do have at least one service (MAKER) capable of dealing with arbitrary URLs.  You would have to create an externally accessible web port and have maker send a message or post a message to maker's site to trigger an event.

Comment: @BillK take note of the date of the answer. That channel did not exist at the time of the answer.

Comment: Then I'm glad I didn't actually-1 it :)

Comment: @BillK Well you should have, because the answer is no longer useful, and in fact is misleading.

Comment: @404 that is not a reason to downvote, that is a reason to edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this via another method though.

write a php script that goes and fetches new items from the tumblr rss and process it, no need to use IFTTT.com

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like Dropbox

Install it on the server and setup an ifttt to write a file. Then monitor the directory locally for changes and trigger events on detection of new file creations

Answer (score 1):

Use Zapier instead, they have Tumblr trigger:
https://zapier.com/zapbook/tumblr/

The action can be a webhook (get, post, put are all supported):
https://zapier.com/zapbook/webhook/

Or any javascript run in node.js, can do http post too:
https://zapier.com/zapbook/code/

Zapier is open to developers, so you could easily create your own Zapier app with triggers and actions if you couldn't find one ready made.

Soon it will be possible to chain apps, similar to how Yahoo! Pipes worked.
Try out the beta: https://zapier.com/manage/add-superpower/flow/